# Ruby on rails, passenger getting handshake error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, passenger, handshake

Any clues why I would be getting the following error when trying my application with 
apache/passenger/mysql while the same runs fine with webtrick?

```
[ 2013-05-12 01:39:31.3313 26429/7f0535e4b700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:762 ]: Could not spawn process for group /home/ruby/work/depot#default: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a handshake message in time.
 in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const std::string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::BackgroundIOCapturerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::DebugDirPtr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:149)
 in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:539)
 in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:205)
 in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:743)
 in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:695)

[ 2013-05-12 01:39:31.3315 26429/7f053688d700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1884 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session. An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a handshake message in time.
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case was removing access to /etc/profile - check if you don't have some blocking calls there or in bashrc/bash_profile etc. Passenger is spawning bash process to start the application and it's reading profile/rc. I know it's late answer but maybe it will help someone.